# How to grab video from google street view Hyperlapse

Tags: google-maps, video

Google created new project based on javascripts. http://hyperlapse.tllabs.io/

Engine creating timelapse video but not generating it as visible video file.

How to get it? Only save from screen by desktop video grabbers?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a way, but its complex.
fist things first though, it wasn't actually made by Google, but by T+L labs using the Google Maps API and JavaScript.
Now, to the  interesting part:
You're right when you say that there is no pre-made way to save the output video, so you have to mess around with the source code (to remove the overlays) before using screen capture.
What you will need:

- Google Chrome
- Screen capture software
- Windows Live movie maker

Steps:

1. First, create your hyper lapse like you normally would.
2. Once you are ready to export, open 'inspect element' (in most browsers the default key is 'F12')
3. A window with lots of text should pop up. drag the edge out to enlarge the window.
4. Move your mouse down over the coloured text. As you do this, different parts of the page should highlight themselves in blue one at a time.
5. What you are seeing is an automatic system; when you hover your mouse over the code for an object on the site, the browser highlights it for you!
6. Move the mouse around until you find the section that highlights the scroll-bar at the bottom of the page.
7. Click once to select it, then press delete. The scroll-bar should vanish.
8. Repeat steps 6-7 for all the other things on top of the hyper lapse itself.
9. You should now have a clear space to record!
10. Finally, before you record, press 'F11' to maximise the window, removing the navigation bar at the top.
11. Activate your screen capture and record the hyper lapse through (Note: make sure the mouse cursor is off-screen whilst you capture)
12. Press 'F11' again to regain the navigation bar, and then 'F5' to refresh the page and get the removed objects back.
13. Use Windows Live movie maker to edit the capture down to the correct section, then export as a high quality film.
14. You're done!

Comment: Thank You, but I am used the same method on first time. And it is not clear solution.